# Php-xml and mysql. Trying to get the correct name based on id

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need some help with this problem.
I cannot figure out how to get the right name out of the xml file based on the id.

The xml file is a bit big so i have made a example.

Books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <book id="23" author="author1" name="bookname1"></book>
    <book id="55" author="author2" name="bookname2"></book>
    <book id="67" author="author3" name="bookname3" ></book>
    <book id="4" author="author4" name="bookname4" ></book>
    <book id="111" author="author5" name="bookname5" ></book>
    <book id="45" author="author6" name="bookname6" ></book>
    <book id="78" author="author7" name="bookname7" ></book>
    <book id="49" author="author8" name="bookname8" ></book>
</list>
```

book.php

```
// Get data from books database
$selectbook = 'SELECT book_id, pages FROM books ORDER BY book_id ASC';
$prepbooks = $connect -> prepare($selectbook);

if ($prepbooks->execute())
{
    $xml_file = "books.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);

    while ($row = $prepbooks->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $book_id = $row['book_id'];
                $pages = $row['pages'];
                echo '<tr><td>book name: ', $book_id,' </td><td>pages: ', $pages, '</td></tr><br>' ;
            }
}
```

The id's in the database are the same ids as in the xml file.

The name is located in the xml file and the amount of pages is located in the mysql database.

When you load book.php there should be a list with the book names and pages.

I'm only able to get a list with ids and pages.
The list is correct but i cannot figure out how to replace the id with the correct name.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Greetings,

Comment: if you have a database for some of the info, why are you storing part of it externally in an xml file?

Comment: it is just an example. sometimes the data change and thats why its connected to the database.

Comment: This script above is almost the same as mine the only thing is that in the database there is a field with date and time  that changes frequently. this is a part of a gameserver and there was no interests to keep data like names in the mysql database.